# Filter on comma separated list

Tags: excel, filter, lookup-tables, validation

I have an Excel spreadsheet that has the following data in column A.  I am using Data Validation to allow only a list selected from a source that contains, in my case, CatA, CatB, and CatC.

```
A1: Categories (header)
A2: CatA, CatB
A3: CatC
A4: CatA, CatB, CatC
```

Currently if I use the filter option, it presents each of these as separate filter selection choices.  Is it possible to list only the options in my source (CatA, CatB, CatC) and then display, for example, columns A2 and A4 if I were to select "CatA"?  I would like to retain the functionality in the single column and maintain the existing values in the column rather than break them into separate columns if possible.

FYI, I am using this reference to [Select Multiple Items from Excel Data Validation List](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2009/09/18/select-multiple-items-from-excel-data-validation-list/) in order to set up the ability to create the data in the column.

Comment: Wildcard would also select records with categories which have "CatA" as a substring...

Comment: You'd need to code something - I don't think there's any way to modify the built-in filtering options

Comment: Thanks for the ideas regarding text filtering for contains.  It suits the ultimate goal but I was hoping for something that would work with the standard filter.